# How can I write a Rake task which depends on task with namespace and parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, rake-task

I have rake tasks which installs and starts neo4j.

```
rake neo4j:install[community-latest, stable]
rake neo4j:start[stable] where `stable` is environment.
```

Now I want to write another rake task something like `rake setup` and create dependency on `rake neo4j:start[stable]` and `rake neo4j:install[community-latest, stable]`

I have tried,

```
task :setup_dev_env => [:neo4j:install[community-latest, stable], :neo4j:start[stable]] do
    puts "Created Rake task"
end
```

obviously this doesn't work, because in the above task `neo4j` is namespace. Then I have changed my task to something like,

```
task :setup_dev_env => [:'neo4j:install[community-latest, stable]', :'neo4j:start[stable]'] do
    puts "Hello rake task working"
end
```

so, at least this solved my issue with `neo4j` namespace, but still couldn't solve the problem.

When I run `rake setup_dev_env` It says

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'neo4j:install[community-latest, stable]' (see --tasks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify that task as:

```
desc 'Some description'
# setup_dev_env is dependent on neo4j:start
task :setup_dev_env,[:stable] => :environment do |t, arg|
param = arg[:stable].nil? ? 'stable' : arg[:stable]
Rake::Task['neo4j:start'].invoke(param)
  puts "Created Rake task"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your task as follow:

```
    desc 'Some description'
    # setup_dev_env is dependent on neo4j:start
    task :setup_dev_env,[:stable] => "neo4j:start" do
      puts "Created Rake task"
    end
```

The above lines of code accept a parameter stable and pass it to neo4j:start. To use stable parameter in neo4j:start, you must have to receive as like:

```
    desc 'Some description'
    # it will be inside namespace neo4j
    task :start, [:stable] do |t, args|
      puts "Created Rake task #{args.inspect}"
    end
```

Comment: Now `rake setup_dev_env[stable]` will work, but how can I hard code `stable` in `setup_dev_env` task it self, so that I don't have to pass `stable` argument while running `rake setup_dev_env`